# Работа с std::vector в С++

Tags: c++, сортировка, vector, предикат

Задача состоит в следующем:

> Дана последовательность чисел. Cледует упорядочить их по неубыванию последней цифры, а при равенстве последних цифр – по неубыванию самих чисел.

Пример:

> Входные данные: 12 15 43 13 20 1 15
>
> Выходные данные: 20 1 12 13 43 15 15

Код:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

bool mySort(int x, int y)
{
    if (x == y)
    {
        return x < y;
    }
    else return x % 10 < y % 10;
}

int main()
{
    vector<int> myVector;

    myVector.push_back(12);
    myVector.push_back(15);
    myVector.push_back(43);
    myVector.push_back(13);
    myVector.push_back(20);
    myVector.push_back(1);
    myVector.push_back(15);

    for (vector<int>::iterator it = myVector.begin(); it != myVector.end(); it++)
        cout << *it << endl;

    cout << endl;

    sort(myVector.begin(), myVector.end(), mySort);

    for (vector<int>::iterator it = myVector.begin(); it != myVector.end(); it++)
        cout << *it << endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Выводится:

> 20 1 12 **43 13** 15 15

Возможно не совсем понял работу предиката, или где-то ошибка(используется однозначное число). Объясните поподробней работу предиката и все,что с этим связано,а также исправьте код.Спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
bool mySort(int x, int y)
{
    if (x % 10 != y % 10) return (x % 10 < y % 10);
    return x < y;
}
```

Вам же *сначала* нужно проверить последнюю цифру, и только если они **равны**, сравнивать сами числа.

Вот рабочий код - https://ideone.com/EgDyWy

Предикат получает два значения из сортируемой коллекции и сравнивает их. Какие именно значения - это уже определяется алгоритмом, но предикат должен обеспечивать слабое упорядочение (кажется, так).

Ваш предикат принимает те же 43 и 13 как равные: поскольку они не равны, он сравнивает их последнюю цифру. А она одна и та же. В результате и на вопрос "43 меньше 13?", и на вопрос "13 меньше 43?" ответ один - нет. А значит, 13 и 43 с точки зрения вашего предиката - равны.

Comment: А те два значения, которые передаются в функцию mySort, берутся с массива как 12 15, 15 43 ?? или как? как они вообще передаются?добавьте в Ваш ответ, пожалуйста.